# How to fix 'Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.' error in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I have been trying to send an email from my website using PHP. However I am unable to and I keep getting this error `Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.` The php email cofiguration has been working fine for the past one year and only recently did I start receiving this error.

I have included smtp settings in my configuration which I did not have before but I still get the same error.
I have gone through the solutions provided in StackOverFlow concerning the error but none seems to work for me.
I have tried to use the different `smtp ports(25,465,587)` but none seem to work.
I have tried different `smtp_crypto(ssl,tls,null)` but none has worked for me.
I have included the line `set_newline("\r\n")` in my code, I have also removed it put the error still persists.
I have even contacted my web hosting service provider but have informed me the problem is not on their side.

My code for sending an email is as shown below

```
class EmailController extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('email');
  }

function send() {
    $config = Array(
    'protocol'  => 'mail',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.(domain_name)',
    'smtp_port' =>  '465',
    'smtp_user' => '********',
    'smtp_pass' => '*********',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
   ); 

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$email_body ="<div>hello world</div>";

$this->email->from('info@myemail.com');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);

    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Your Email has successfully been sent.';
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be the message "Your Email has successfully been sent" and an email to be sent but I keep get the following error message;

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Date: Date and time stamp
From: <info@myemail.com>
Return-Path: <info@myemail.com>
Reply-To: <info@myemail.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: info@myemail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5d234afb2e34a@myemail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5d234afb2e38e"
=?UTF-8?Q?Orders=20not=20being=20sent?=
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

My Order

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

My Order
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: `'protocol'  => 'mail',` ensures your stmp setting won't be honored.

Comment: @mario is okay to use `'protocol' => 'smtp',` and `'smtp_host'=>'mail.(domain_name)',`??

Comment: With the proper syntax and server information, perhaps.

Comment: @mario I tried it and it worked thanks. Though I had to change the smtp_port to 25

Comment: 'protocol'  => 'mail', to 'protocol'  => 'smtp',